# jQuery, how to replace the value of a slider with thousand seperator?

Tags: jquery, slider, slide

I have a simple slider and would like to add a thousand seperator to its value.
I managed to get the slider value and implement the thousand seperator, but how can I replace the value of the slider with this new (thousand seperator) value, live on the site?
Below my code:

```
$(".btQuoteSlider").on("slide", function(event, ui) {
    var tw_turnover_total = ui.value;           
    var tw_turnover_total_formatted = tw_turnover_total.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, Number(10000).toLocaleString().substring(2, 3));

    //Below sets the value attribute, but I want to change the text() of the div .btQuoteSliderValue
    $(".tw_omzet_slider .btQuoteSliderValue").attr("value",tw_turnover_total_formatted);
});
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML in the question too, so that we can create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You want to change the text of the div?  `$(".btQuoteSliverValue").text(tw_turnover_total_formatted)`;_

Comment: Are you having trouble setting the text value or formatting the value?

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried that, but that will only change the value if I set a setTimeout function. Can I somehow replace the ui.value ?

Comment: TBH not sure what your question is asking.  How to add a `,` separator?  How to set a value into a div?  How to set value on a jquery-ui (?) slider without needing a setTimeout.   Can you clarify exactly what your issue is, preferrably with [mcve] and/or expected outputs.

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, set the new slider value (with thousand seperator) without needing to set a timeout. Somehow using `text()` only works when setting a timeout